# Jquery loop outputting the wrong error message for form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I am having trouble with setting up the proper conditions for validating a form.

Line 46: `if (input.value == '' && mail_type_selector.val() == null)`

If a mail type is not selected and only the last input(Mail width) is filled and the rest out are empty. It should still output the
error msg: "Please fill out the required field(s) and select a mail type"

but it's outputting the message 'Please select a mail type' from the condition on line 34.

How can I ensure that the jquery each loop will output the error message from the condition on line 46 in the event that only the last input field is filled and the rest are empty?

```js
/* ==========================================================================
                               DOM Elements
    ========================================================================== */
const error_msg_section = $('#error_msg_section');
const mail_type_selector = $('#mail_type_selector');


/* ==========================================================================
                                Validate form
    ========================================================================== */


function checkForm() {
  let error_msg_text = '';
  let is_form_valid = true;


  $('form input[required]:visible').each(function(index, input) {

    let input_name = $(this).attr('name');
    let input_label = $(this).prev('label');

    // Check if a field has no value
    if (input.value === '') {

      // Add class to inputs label to indicate that it has no value
      input_label.addClass('empty-input');

      error_msg_text = 'Please fill out the required field(s)';

    } else input_label.removeClass('empty-input');


    // Check if a mail  type is not selected
    if (mail_type_selector.val() === null) {

      mail_type_selector.addClass('error-option-not-selected');

      error_msg_text = 'Please select a mail type';

    } else mail_type_selector.removeClass('error-option-not-selected');



    // Check if a field has no value and if a mail type is not selected
    if (input.value == '' && mail_type_selector.val() == null) {

      error_msg_text = 'Please fill out the required field(s) and select a mail type';

      mail_type_selector.addClass('error-option-not-selected');
    }


    // Append the error message to the error section paragraph
    error_msg_section.text(error_msg_text);

    // Check if the element contains an error message
    if (error_msg_section.text() !== '') {

      is_form_valid = false; // Set to false to indicate that the form is invalid
      error_msg_section.addClass('display-error-msg'); // Display the error message on the UI

    } else {
      error_msg_section.removeClass('display-error-msg');
    }
  });


return is_form_valid;
}


/* ==========================================================================
                            Send Form
========================================================================== */

$('.destinations button').click(function(e) {


  e.preventDefault();

  checkForm()
})

console.log('test')
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

form>section {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px 15px 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #00000061;
}

.input-fields {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 1em;
}

.input-fields>div {
  display: grid;
}

.input-fields>div>label {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.shipping-info .input-fields,
button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}


.input-fields label.empty-input {
  color: red;
}

#error_msg_section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

#error_msg_section.display-error-msg {
  display: block;
}


select.error-option-not-selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <section class="destinations">
    <p>Destination</p>

    <div class="input-fields">

      <div>
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <select>
          <option disabled selected>Please select a country</option>
          <option>US</option>
          <option>CA</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <button>Send</button>
  </section>

  <section class="shipping-info">
    <p>Shipping information</p>

    <select id="mail_type_selector">
      <option disabled selected>Please select a mail type</option>
      <option>Letter</option>
      <option>Package</option>
    </select>

    <div class="input-fields">

      <div>
        <label for="mail_weight">Mail weight</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_weight" name="mail_weight" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mail_length">Mail length</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_length" name="mail_length" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mail_height">Mail height</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_height" name="mail_height" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mail_width">Mail width</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_width" name="mail_width" required>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</form>

<p id="error_msg_section"></p>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the logic that checks if the mail_type_selector has a value to outside of the each loop, i.e.

```js
/* ==========================================================================
                               DOM Elements
    ========================================================================== */
const error_msg_section = $('#error_msg_section');
const mail_type_selector = $('#mail_type_selector');


/* ==========================================================================
                                Validate form
    ========================================================================== */


function checkForm() {
  let error_msg_text = '';
  let is_form_valid = true;


  $('form input[required]:visible').each(function(index, input) {

    let input_name = $(this).attr('name');
    let input_label = $(this).prev('label');

    // Check if a field has no value
    if (input.value === '') {

      // Add class to inputs label to indicate that it has no value
      input_label.addClass('empty-input');

      error_msg_text = 'Please fill out the required field(s)';

    } else input_label.removeClass('empty-input');
  });

  // Check if a mail  type is not selected
  if (mail_type_selector.val() === null) {
    // Check if any of the input fields have already triggered a validation message
    if (error_msg_text) {
      error_msg_text = 'Please fill out the required field(s) and select a mail type';
      mail_type_selector.addClass('error-option-not-selected');
    } else {
      mail_type_selector.addClass('error-option-not-selected');
      error_msg_text = 'Please select a mail type';
    }
  } else mail_type_selector.removeClass('error-option-not-selected');

  // Append the error message to the error section paragraph
  error_msg_section.text(error_msg_text);

  // Check if the element contains an error message
  if (error_msg_section.text() !== '') {
    is_form_valid = false; // Set to false to indicate that the form is invalid
    error_msg_section.addClass('display-error-msg'); // Display the error message on the UI

  } else {
    error_msg_section.removeClass('display-error-msg');
  }

  return is_form_valid;
}


/* ==========================================================================
                            Send Form
========================================================================== */

$('.destinations button').click(function(e) {


  e.preventDefault();

  checkForm()
})

console.log('test')
```

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

form>section {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px 15px 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #00000061;
}

.input-fields {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 1em;
}

.input-fields>div {
  display: grid;
}

.input-fields>div>label {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.shipping-info .input-fields,
button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.input-fields label.empty-input {
  color: red;
}

#error_msg_section {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

#error_msg_section.display-error-msg {
  display: block;
}

select.error-option-not-selected {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <section class="destinations">
    <p>Destination</p>

    <div class="input-fields">

      <div>
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <input type="text" id="state" name="state" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="zip">Zip</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <select>
          <option disabled selected>Please select a country</option>
          <option>US</option>
          <option>CA</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <button>Send</button>
  </section>

  <section class="shipping-info">
    <p>Shipping information</p>

    <select id="mail_type_selector">
      <option disabled selected>Please select a mail type</option>
      <option>Letter</option>
      <option>Package</option>
    </select>

    <div class="input-fields">

      <div>
        <label for="mail_weight">Mail weight</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_weight" name="mail_weight" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mail_length">Mail length</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_length" name="mail_length" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mail_height">Mail height</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_height" name="mail_height" required>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label for="mail_width">Mail width</label>
        <input type="text" id="mail_width" name="mail_width" required>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</form>

<p id="error_msg_section"></p>
```

To simplify validation I would suggest moving to a library such as jQuery validation (https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: Thank you!! It worked like a charm!

And okay I'll be sure to check it out